# Question on Snake lemma

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

we have Short exact sequence of chain complexe $0\rightarrow C\xrightarrow[]{f}D\xrightarrow[]{g}E\rightarrow 0$ i want to prove that there existe a longue exact sequence of modules
$$...\rightarrow H_{n+1}(E)\xrightarrow[]{\delta} H_n(C)\xrightarrow[]{f_*} H_n(D)\xrightarrow[]{g_*} H_n(E)\xrightarrow[]{\delta} H_{n-1}(C)\rightarrow ...$$

I proved the existence of $\delta$ and the exactness at $H_n(E)$ and at $H_n(D)$

but i dont know how to prove that $\ker f_* = Im \delta$ ?

i proved that $Im \delta \subset \ker f_*$ but how to prove that $\ker f_* \subset Im \delta$ ???

Let $[x] \in \ker f_*$ so $0=f_*[x]=[f_n(x)]$ then ther exist $y\in D_n$ such that $f_n(x)=\partial_{n+1}^2 y$, 
how to find $z$ such that $\delta[z]=[x]$ ???????

**Can i say that is there existe $[z]$ such that $\delta [z]=[x]$ from the construction of $\delta$ ?**
Please

thank you.

Comment: this is not even the snake lemma